# seeking excel formula that return result that have max value in corresponding column

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I have Excel sheet. In that there column for "Zone" like east, west etc. Each zone have many State in corresponding column, and in third column there value for each State. See below image

[image]

Now I don't know how to get State in particular Zone that have maximum value.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This requires an array formula.

```
=INDEX(B2:B10,MATCH(E2&MAX(IF(A2:A10=E2,C2:C10)),INDEX(A2:A10&C2:C10,0),0))
```

Confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Alternatively, you could build a pivot table with a few clicks. Set the filter to Zone, State in the rows, Max of Value in the Values area and restrict the pivot to show the top 1 only. Then set the filter to a zone.

[image]

Comment: If this helped, please accept my post as the answer as explained in the [Tour]. That's how to say thanks here.